# Remove marginetop a relative layout dynamically if another layout is generated in between two relative layout

Tags: android

I have two relative layout say relative layout1 & 2 having an edit text and a button. In order to provide spacing in between I specified margin top of 30dp to relative layout2. Another relative layout 3 is generated dynamically in between them when we click button of the relative layout1. If so I have to remove margin top of relative layout2 programatically.

snapshot is like below

[image]

In this case a provide padding in xml. But when another layout is added in between like this

[image]

the padding is not preferable. I have to remove padding programmatically. How can i do that by checking whether there is a layout in between and remove that padding. I am a beginner in android coding....

Answer (score 1):

You can set margins, or anything else regarding a layout like this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)relativeLayout.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.setMargins(80, 0, 0, 0); // left, top, right, bottom
relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

You can find more Information on LayoutParams here: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove padding call

```
relativeLayout.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
```